# basic mod_rewrite / regexp question: Split ID with dash

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do some htaccess redirects for cleaner URL's, but I failed to do.

Here is my intend:

```
/kitap/blah     => kitap.php?a=blah
/kitap/blah-123 => kitap.php?a=blah&b=123
```

This is my current code.

```
RewriteRule ^(kitap|yazar)/?([^/\.]+)?(-([0-9]+))?/?$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$3 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Currently it producing this:

```
/kitap/blah     => kitap.php?a=blah
/kitap/blah-123 => kitap.php?a=blah-123
```

The word "blah" can include Unicode characters, like ç,ö,ğ,ş etc. (This means [a-z0-9_] will not work in my situation)

How can I accomplish my intended result? I tried various things but no success. Thanks.

Comment: Can't you add the `-` inside `[^/\.]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a "hybrid" solution from Alin and battal's comments.

```
RewriteRule ^(kitap|yazar)/?([^/\.-]+)?(-([0-9]+))?/?$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

And it works. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteRule ^(kitap|yazar)/?([^/\.-]+)?(-(\d+))?/?$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^(kitap|yazar)/?(\p{L}+)?(-(\d+))?/?$ $1.php?a=$2&b=$4 [QSA,L,NC]
```

`$4`, not `$3` unless you intend to use the dash `-`, if you use `$3`, `$_GET['b']` will be equal to `-123`. Every pair of parantheses counts, so that `$3` is `-123`, whereas `$4` is `123`.

`\p` means a unicode character, and `{L}` means a letter. You can see available modifiers at [PHP PCRE regex - Unicode character properties](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php). To use them, your version of PHP must be compiled with `--enable-unicode-properties`.

Comment: That's not quite right. `\p` does not mean a Unicode character. It means one character with the following property.

Comment: Yeah but, it's the only special class that supports unicode and it's used only in Unicode context. Just look at the URL of the relevant manual page. Otherwise, it wouldn't be any different from, say, `\w`. Yes, `\p` is a unicode character, it encompasses the unicode plane.